# Difference Between Adiabatic and Superconducting Quantum Computing

Tags: superconductivity, quantum-computer, adiabatic

Wikipedia (not the most stringent source, I know) has separate pages for [adiabatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_quantum_computation) and [superconducting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_quantum_computing) quantum computing. It's my understanding that all superconducting quantum computers are adiabatic and vice versa. Is this not the case? If not, what are the differences? I know that the adiabatic page starts by referring to quantum annealers, but it goes on to refer to universal adiabatic QC, so presumably this isn't where the distinction in terminology lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are classifications of quantum computing devices in two different dimensions:

An adiabatic quantum computer is a device that essentially realizes a computation in terms of an adiabatic process. It starts by preparing the ground state to some simple Hamiltonian $\hat{H}_1$ which is adiabatically turned into a more complex Hamiltonian $\hat{H}_2$ whose ground state actually represents the solution to the given problem. This computation approach is different from the classical approach to quantum computation but [it has been shown](https://doi.org/10.1137%2Fs0097539705447323) that classical quantum computing algorithms can efficiently be simulated by such an adiabatic approach.

Superconducting quantum computing, on the other hand, denotes a set of approaches to realize qubits in quantum computing devices. Here the qubits are realized with Josephson junctions. But there are also other approaches for this. See, e.g., the [Wikipedia article on qubits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit#Physical_representation).

Comment: Thanks for answering, although perhaps I didn't state myself well enough as I'm aware of the distinction between universal quantum computers and annealers. The Wikipedia article however, specifically mentions universal adiabatic quantum computation. From what I've been able to find I'm not sure how this differs from superconducting quantum computation.

Comment: @TobyHawkins As the answer states, these are "orthogonal" concepts.  Adiabatic is like asking about programming languages, and superconducting about CPU architectures.  (In particular, the first is a software concept, and the latter a hardware concept.) Any language will run on any architecture, though certain languages might be suited better for certain architectures.

Comment: @Gregor Adiabatic computing is not synonymous to annealing, but a scheme to carry out quantum computing by adiabatically changing a Hamiltonian, and has been shown to be universal for quantum computing.

Comment: @Norbert: Thank you for the clarification. I actually realized that my answer may not be 100% accurate after reading wikipedia article. I now changed it and hope that I integrated your points in the right way.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks @Norbert and Gregor for taking the time to respond.